# Adjusting a Search Time

Tags: windows, visual-c++

I'm doing a search on files.  I need to adjust the search time from the current time (filetime) to current time(file time) less one minute. How would I do this. Thisis what I have so far. Thank you.

```
struct file_data 
{ 
std::wstring sLastAccessTime; 
__int64 nFileSize; 
}; 

int GetFileList(const wchar_t *searchkey, std::map<std::wstring, file_data> &map) 
{ 
    WIN32_FIND_DATA fd; 
    HANDLE h = FindFirstFile(searchkey,&fd); 
    if(h == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) 
{ 
    return 0; // no files found 
} 
while(1) 
{ 
    wchar_t buf[128]; 
    FILETIME ft = fd.ftLastWriteTime; 
    SYSTEMTIME sysTime; 
    FileTimeToSystemTime(&ft, &sysTime); 
    wsprintf(buf, L"%d-%02d-%02d",sysTime.wYear, sysTime.wMonth, sysTime.wDay); 

    file_data filedata; 
    filedata.sLastAccessTime= buf; 
    filedata.nFileSize      = (((__int64)fd.nFileSizeHigh) << 32) + fd.nFileSizeLow; 

    map[fd.cFileName]= filedata; 

    if (FindNextFile(h, &fd) == FALSE) 
        break; 
} 
return map.size(); 
} 

int main() 
{ 
std::map<std::wstring, file_data> map; 
GetFileList(L"C:\\Users\\DS\\Downloads\\*.jpg", map); 
GetFileList(L"C:\\Users\\DS\\Downloads\\*.txt", map); 
int count = GetFileList(L"C:\\Users\\DS\\Downloads\\*.pdf", map);

for(std::map<std::wstring, file_data>::const_iterator it = map.begin(); 
    it != map.end(); ++it) 
{
```

Comment: I would like to get the file that are less than a minute old. Thank you.

Comment: Pretty unclear.  Use SystemTimeToFileTime and subtract 60 * 1000 * 10000LL from it.  That's the FILETIME of a minute ago.

Comment: Right now I am getting all pdf,txt and jpg fileds from the directory. But I only want the ones that are a minute or less old. Or should we say a minute or less young!

Comment: Use ftCreationTime instead of ftLastWriteTime.

Comment: Thank you. Done, but where and how do I set the time - minute. I would imagine its best in FILETIME.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `GetSystemTimeAsFileTime` to get the current time in `FILETIME` format. Subtract 6000000000 to go back in time one minute. Use `CompareFileTime` to compare each file's time against that value.

Comment: Sound good! I'm a little new to this. Do you have an example and where in the code would it go? Thank you, Raymond.

Comment: I was hoping that the nudges would be enough to get you to read some more documentation. `FILETIME ftNow; GetSystemTimeAsFileTime(&ftNow); auto ftAs64 = ftOneMinuteAgo.dwLowDateTime + ((unsigned __int64)ftOneMinuteAgo.dwHighDateTime << 32) - 6000000000UL; FILETIME ftOneMinuteAgo = { (DWORD)ftAs64, (DWORD)(ftAs64 >> 32) };` That's the solution for the first two sentences. I'll let you try to solve the third.

Comment: Thank you Raymond.  Your nudging did work. I searched and read. I appreciate the input.  I'm a VB programmer and I just started learning C++ and it's very differnt from what I am use to! I will try to figure out the rest....

Comment: Same place you would put it in VB. Before adding the entry to the map, check the file time.

Comment: Thank you Raymond. Will do, but was that the last part or is there more after that?

Comment: I helped you with the Windows-y part. The rest is just programming.

Comment: Thank you Raymond..This is what I did.....but am getting ftOneMinuteAgo is undefined.

Comment: I'll leave fixing the typo as an exercise to ensure that you understand what you're doing instead of just copy/pasting blindly.

Comment: Ah-Huh! Chicanery! No just kidding! I appreciate the help! :)

Comment: Oh my Oh my. Please put me out of my misery, I have only been doing this for a couple of months and obviously I don't know what I am doing (yet).  Its telling me that ftOneMinuteAgo has no structure/class or union. Thank you Raymond.

Comment: Problem Solved. Now I will do the compare time part.