# Map Isn't Returning Correct Numbers

Tags: windows, visual-c++

I have a map that is acting up and not returning the correct number.  It did then it didn't, now it's just not returning. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

```
struct file_data 
{ 
    std::wstring sLastAccessTime; 
    __int64 nFileSize      ; 
};

int GetFileList(const wchar_t *searchkey, std::map<std::wstring, file_data> &map) 
{ 
    WIN32_FIND_DATA fd; 
    HANDLE h = FindFirstFile(searchkey,&fd); 
    if(h == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) 
    { 
        return 0; // no files found 
    } 

    while(1) 
    { 
        wchar_t buf[128]; 
        FILETIME ft = fd.ftLastWriteTime; 
        SYSTEMTIME sysTime; 
        FileTimeToSystemTime(&ft, &sysTime); 
        wsprintf(buf, L"%d-%02d-%02d",sysTime.wYear, sysTime.wMonth, sysTime.wDay); 

        file_data filedata; 
        filedata.sLastAccessTime= buf; 
        filedata.nFileSize      = (((__int64)fd.nFileSizeHigh) << 32) + fd.nFileSizeLow; 

        map[fd.cFileName]= filedata; 

        if (FindNextFile(h, &fd) == FALSE) 
            break; 
    } 
    return map.size(); 
} 

int main() 
{ 
    std::map<std::wstring, file_data> map; 
    int count = GetFileList(L"C:\\Users\\DS\\Downloads\\*.pdf", map); 
    int count1 = GetFileList(L"C:\\Users\\DS\\Downloads\\*.txt", map); 
    int count2 = GetFileList(L"C:\\Users\\DS\\Downloads\\*.jpg", map);

    for(std::map<std::wstring, file_data>::const_iterator it = map.begin(); it != map.end(); ++it) 
    {
        if (count2 != 0) 
        { 
            printf("\n   How Many: %i   \n", count2);
        } 
        else 
        { 
            printf ("%s \n", "Nothing");
        } 
        return 0; 
    }
}
```

Comment: are we supposed to debug your ignorance ? fix your indentation !

Comment: you call that "fixed" ?? now, i did fix it !

Comment: Fix it some more.  The indentation is still a mess.  Also, please explain what you're expecting and what you're actually getting.  The loop at the end doesn't make much sense.  You're effectively going to print out the total number of items in the map once for each item in the map.

Comment: sure i can help: learn how to use your debugger ! the first useful tool of a programmer is the debuger. step through the program, break at the call to `FindFirstFile()`. what does `fd` contain ? continue to step through the execution, at which moment do you get strange values ?

Comment: This appears to be exactly the same program as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7606098/adjusting-a-search-time/7607307  You can't just say "not returning the correct number" since you haven't said what the correct number is. You need to say what you expect and what you actually get.

Comment: it seems your biggest problem is that your way of programming is a big mess... by the way, your `GetFileList()` function works like a charm, it performs exactly as it is written.

Comment: Raymond I am getting 7 and the correct answer should be 3. I have 2 text files and 1 jpg. Thank you.

Comment: @RaymondChen: Welcome!  Love your blog.  I look forward to seeing you get a gold `winapi` badge, although you'd better get cracking if you want to beat Hand Passant to the first one.

Answer (score 1):

Note that `GetFileList()` returns the number of items in the map.

In your implementation it is cumulative. Maybe you want to clear the map between consecutive calls to `GetFileList()`.

Comment: Right it is cumulative. And I just want the total number of the three file types. Right now I'm getting 7 and it should be 3. How can I fix this? Thank you, Lior.

Comment: Lior, Tried this and it returned nothing.      std::map<std::wstring, file_data> map; 
int count = GetFileList(L"C:\\Users\\DS\\Downloads\\*.pdf", map);
map.clear();
int count1 = GetFileList(L"C:\\Users\\DS\\Downloads\\*.txt", map);
map.clear();
int count2 = GetFileList(L"C:\\Users\\DS\\Downloads\\*.jpg", map);
map.clear();

Comment: what do you mean "returned nothing"  `count`, `count1`, and `count2` are all zero?

Comment: It returned NULL...but I have the solution.  I have to wait an hour...too new. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

OK found the solution. This is it.

```
GetFileList(L"C:\\Users\\DS\\Downloads\\*.pdf", map);
GetFileList(L"C:\\Users\\DS\\Downloads\\*.txt", map);
GetFileList(L"C:\\Users\\DS\\Downloads\\*.jpg", map);

if( map.size() > 0 
  then...........
```